# How to change .htaccess rewrite rules to web.config

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-config, windows-server

I have no idea of web.config I have written some rewrite rules in .htacess , but how to convert those in web.config. I found out about IIS but I was not able to understand anything.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L] 

RewriteRule ^payment/([^/]*)$ /vhil/checkout?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /vhil/product-desc?p=$1 [L]

#admin rules
RewriteRule ^admin/edit/product/([^/]*)$ /vhil/admin/editProduct?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/edit/banner/([^/]*)$ /vhil/admin/editBanner?id=$1 [L]
```